# How to store value to prevent loose after updating my discord bot?

Tags: discord.js

I am currently creating a discord bot following [discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide/) (node.js+discord.js) and I get the bases (commands,config files). I succesfully loaded my bot to my server but I am sure I will improve it over time.

**So how do I store value/data ?** (user level, user point, user custom counter etc)

I am aware of the existence of database and json file but I am not quite sure it will do the trick.
I was wondering if **it is possible to download/retrieve file from my bot, then reload it** after update. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution would be to use a database. You can take mysql for example.
And use guild.id and user.id as keys for SELECT.

Some examples for [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql):

Create database

```sql
CREATE DATABASE myBase
use myBase
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `guildId` varchar(255),
  `userId` varchar(255),
  `lvl` int
);
```

Create a pool for connect to database

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 15,
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'myBase',
});

module.exports = pool;
```

create file with select, create and update mysql DATA.

```js
const pool = require('./pool');
const get = (guildId, userId) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId = ${userId} && guildId = ${guildId}`, (err, rows) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (rows.length === 0) {
                resolve(create(guildId, userId));
            } else if (rows) {
                resolve(rows[0]);
            } else {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    });
};

const create = (guildId, userId) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let data = {
                guildId: guildId,
                userId: userId,
                lvl: 1,
            };
            pool.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', data, (err, result) => {
                resolve(get(guildId, userId));
            });
    });
};

const update = (guildId, userId, data) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        get(guildId, userId).then(user => {
            pool.query(`UPDATE users SET ? WHERE _id = ${user.id}`, data, (err, result) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                resolve(get(guildId, userId));
            });
        });
    });
};

module.exports.get = get
module.exports.create = create
module.exports.update = update
```

Some example to use in bot.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = '?';
const token = require('./token.json').token;
const mysqlUser = require('./mysqlUser');
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Bot is ready`);
});

client.on('message', (message) => {
    /* s *Check for message starts with prefix */
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    /* split message to array */
    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(' ');
    /* get command */
    let command = args.shift();
    if (command === 'lvl') {
        mysqlUser.get(message.guild.id, message.author.id).then((user) => {
            message.channel.send(`${message.author} your lvl is ${user.lvl}`);
        });
    }
});

client.login(token);
```